# Converting from javascript to angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, whitespace

I have the following code and I need to convert it to Angular Js..also I'd like to stop the user from entering a space only at the start (can't input space bar before any text)

`<input type="text" name="firstname" runat="server" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace()">`

```
 function AvoidSpace() { 
         var x=document.forms["firs`enter code here`tname"].value;
                            if (event.keyCode == 32 ) { 
                                    event.returnValue = false; 
                                    return false; 
                            } 
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to filter space key press you can use the `pattern` feature of `input type=text`.

html5 only: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text

angularjs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[text]

```
<input ng-pattern="[^\s+]" type="text" name="firstname">
```

**update:**

you can use the directive ngKeypress:

```
<input ng-pattern="[^\s+]" type="text" name="firstname" ng-keyup="checkinput($event)">
```

controller:

```
$scope.checkinput = function(keyevt){
  if (keyevt.keyCode === 32 ) { 
     keyevt.returnValue = false; 
     return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC pattern only trigger form validation but it doesn't stop the user from entering the text.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I decided to use angular js because I already have a pattern I'm using which is : "^[^&<>\"'/]*$ and when I tried to combine that /s for whitespace with mine it didn't work.

Comment: in order to add the space rule to your pattern you should use `^[^&<>\"'\/\s]*$`.  I tested it on regeex101.com and it functions well. For the previous update thanks to @Icycool suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" runat="server" ng-keypress="AvoidSpace()">
```

function in controller

```
$scope.AvoidSpace = function AvoidSpace() { 
         var x=document.forms["firs`enter code here`tname"].value;
                            if (event.keyCode == 32 ) { 
                                    event.returnValue = false; 
                                    return false; 
                            } 
                    }
```

Comment: You might have to pass in $event from the view for it to be available in the function.